# How to sort array by value, with access to key in callback function?

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array that I would like to sort based on its values. However, because values can be equivalent, I need to be able to access the keys in the sort function's callback as well in order to figure out the correct ordering. I am currently using uasort in order to sort by value, while maintaining key association, but cannot figure out how to access the keys from the callback comparison function.

**Example array:**

```
Array(
    [a1] => date1,
    [a2] => date2,
    [a3] => date1
)
```

I need to sort by the dates, but since `a1` and `a3` are the same date, I need to check whether it's `a1` or `a3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to sort by value, then by key. To do this you can use [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and pass first your values then your keys:

```
$k = array_keys($array);
$v = array_values($array);

array_multisort($array, SORT_ASC, $v, SORT_ASC, $k);
```

Example output (after `print_r($array)`):

```
Array
(
    [a1] => date1
    [a3] => date1
    [a2] => date2
)
```